# GODOT 4 - Data not transferring to server from connected clients

Tags: signals, nodes, instance, godot, multiplayer

I have a multiplayer project setup, with the intention of creating a survival game. In this survival game I have player inventories, external inventories such as chests, and the player is able to drop items with the items de-instancing from their inventory, transferring the data to the server, and then instancing the object on the server with its specific properties saved.

The problem I am having is for the server host, the drop item mechanic works as intended. However when a client joins the server (they can move, interact with objects, pickup any objects instantiated at runtime, and "shoot" other players with that data transferring to the server, then to "hit" clients), and the client tries to drop an item, it will emit the signal but the server won't accept that it received the data, and it wont instance the node for anybody.

Player code that emits a signal to the server & sends the data:

```
> func _on_inventory_drop_slot_data(grabbed_slot_data) -> void:
>   
>   print_debug("Sending object to server.")
>   drop_item.emit(grabbed_slot_data)
```

Server code that receives the data and instances the data as a node on the server:

```
> func _on_inventory_drop_slot_data(grabbed_slot_data) -> void:
>   print_debug("Server is receiving object.")
>   if grabbed_slot_data:
> print_debug(grabbed_slot_data)
>   else:
> print_debug("no slot data")
>   var pick_up = PickUp.instantiate()
>   pick_up.slot_data = grabbed_slot_data
>   pick_up.position = Vector3(0,10,0)
>   add_child(pick_up)
```

From my understanding, once an item is instanced for everyone on the server end, everyone should be able to see the object, right? If that isn't the case, do I use a MultiplayerSpawner node to instance dropped items across all clients as you do with player instancing?

Here is the full player code if you'd like to look through it.

```
> extends CharacterBody3D
> 
> signal health_changed(health_value)
> signal drop_item(grabbed_slot_data)
> 
> @onready var PickUp = preload("res://item/pickup/pickup.tscn")
> 
> @onready var inventoryHUD = $PlayerInventory/InventoryHUD
> @onready var player_inventory = $PlayerInventory/InventoryHUD/Inventory
> @onready var inventorySubviewport = $PlayerInventory/InventoryHUD/Background/SubViewportContainer
> @onready var hot_bar_inventory = $PlayerInventory/InventoryHUD/Inventory/HotBarInventory
> 
> @onready var interact_ray = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/Head/InteractRay
> @onready var fpshealthbar = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/FirstPersonHUD/Health
> @onready var tpshealthbar = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/FirstPersonHUD/HealthBack
> 
> @onready var camera = null
> @onready var fpscamera = $FPSCamera
> @onready var tpscamera = $TPSCamera
> 
> @onready var anim_rig = $AnimationRig
> @onready var anim_arms = $AnimationArms
> @onready var anim_tpsc = $AnimationTPSC
> @onready var anim_weapon = $Weapon/AnimationWeapon
> 
> @onready var head = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/Head
> @onready var tpshead = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/ThirdArmSpine/SpineToArm/ThirdArmUpper/ThirdArmMidsection/ThirdArmLower/ThirdCamera
> @onready var righthand = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/RightShoulder/RightArmUpper/RightArmLower/RightHand
> @onready var rightpalm = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/RightShoulder/RightArmUpper/RightArmLower/RightHand/RightPalm
> @onready var leftshoulder = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/LeftShoulder
> @onready var rightshoulder = $Rig/Skeleton3D/Waist/Spine/Torso/RightShoulder
> 
> @onready var weapon = $Weapon
> @onready var raycast = $Weapon/Yeetcast
> @onready var aimposition = $Weapon/aimposition
> @onready var muzzle_flash = $Weapon/MuzzleFlash
> 
> @export var inventory_data: InventoryData
> @export var weapon_slot_1_data: InventoryDataEquip
> @export var weapon_slot_2_data: InventoryDataEquip
> @export var weapon_slot_3_data: InventoryDataEquipHeavy
> @export var mod_slot_1_data: InventoryDataEquipMod
> @export var mod_slot_2_data: InventoryDataEquipMod
> @export var mod_slot_3_data: InventoryDataEquipMod
> 
> @onready var weapon_model_1 = null
> @onready var weapon_model_2 = null
> @onready var weapon_model_3 = null
> 
> var weapon_1_id = null
> var weapon_2_id = null
> var weapon_3_id = null
> 
> var SPEED = Globals.PlayerSpeed
> var CROUCHSPEED = Globals.PlayerCrouchSpeed
> var CRAWLSPEED = Globals.PlayerCrawlSpeed
> var SPRINTSPEED = Globals.PlayerSprintSpeed
> var JUMPSPEED = Globals.PlayerJumpSpeed
> 
> var gravity = Globals.PlayerGravity
> var health: int = Globals.PlayerHealth
> var PlayerInQuestion = Globals.PlayerInQuestion
> #var damage: int = slot_data.item_data_equip.attack_value
> 
> var equipped_weapon_1 = false
> var equipped_weapon_2 = false
> var equipped_weapon_3 = false
> 
> var freelook = false
> var crouching = false
> var sprinting = false
> var crawling = false
> var walking = false
> var shooting = false
> var aiming = false
> var inspecting = false
> var pausing = false
> var inventory = false
> var collections = false
> 
> func _enter_tree():
>   
>   set_multiplayer_authority(str(name).to_int())
> 
> func _ready():
>   
>   if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
>   Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
>   camera = fpscamera
>   
>   player_inventory.set_player_inventory_data(self.inventory_data)
>   player_inventory.set_weapon_slot_1_inventory_data(self.weapon_slot_1_data)
>   player_inventory.set_weapon_slot_2_inventory_data(self.weapon_slot_2_data)
>   player_inventory.set_weapon_slot_3_inventory_data(self.weapon_slot_3_data)
>   player_inventory.set_mod_slot_1_inventory_data(self.mod_slot_1_data)
>   player_inventory.set_mod_slot_2_inventory_data(self.mod_slot_2_data)
>   player_inventory.set_mod_slot_3_inventory_data(self.mod_slot_3_data)
>   
>   for node in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("external_inventory"):
> node.toggle_inventory.connect(toggle_inventory_interface)
>   hot_bar_inventory.set_inventory_data(self.inventory_data)
>   #get_parent().instantiate_pickup.connect(on_instantiate_pickup)
> 
> func _unhandled_input(event):
> 
>   if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
> 
>   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("quit"):
> if pausing:
> pausing = false
> else:
> pausing = true
> inventory = false
> inventoryHUD.visible = false
> player_inventory.visible = false
> Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
> 
>   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("inventory"):
> toggle_inventory_interface()
> 
>   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("collections"):
> 
> if collections:
> collections = false
> else:
> collections = true
> 
>   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("interact"):
> if inventory:
> toggle_inventory_interface()
> if interact_ray.is_colliding():
> interact_ray.get_collider().player_interact()
> 
>   if not pausing and not inventory and not collections:
> if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
> if freelook:
> camera.rotate_y(-event.relative.x * .005)
> else:
> rotate_y(-event.relative.x * .005)
> camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * .005)
> camera.rotation.x = clamp(camera.rotation.x, -PI/2, PI/2)
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("inspect equipped"):
> inspecting = true
> print_debug("Inspecting")
> if Input.is_action_just_released("inspect equipped"):
> inspecting = false
> print_debug("No longer Inspecting")
> 
> if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
> if Input.is_action_pressed("crouch"):
> crawling = true
> print_debug("Crawling.")
> else:
> sprinting = true
> elif Input.is_action_just_released("sprint"):
> sprinting = false
> crawling = false
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
> velocity.y = JUMPSPEED
> 
> if Input.is_action_pressed("crouch"):
> crouching = true
> print_debug("Crouching.")
> elif Input.is_action_just_released("crouch"):
> crouching = false
> crawling = false
> anim_rig.play("rig stand")
> 
> if Input.is_action_pressed("freelook"):
> freelook = true
> print_debug("Freelook.")
> elif Input.is_action_just_released("freelook"):
> freelook = false
> camera.rotation = Vector3(0,0,0)
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("swap cameras") and camera == tpscamera:
> print_debug("FPS Camera")
> fpscamera.current = true
> camera = fpscamera
> elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("swap cameras") and camera == fpscamera:
> print_debug("TPS Camera")
> fpscamera.current = false
> tpscamera.current = true
> camera = tpscamera
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("lean left"):
> tpscamera.position.x = tpscamera.position.x - 1
> tpscamera.position.y = tpscamera.position.y - .4
> if tpscamera.position.x < -1:
> tpscamera.position.x = -1
> if tpscamera.position.y < 2.9:
> tpscamera.position.y = 2.9
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("lean right"):
> tpscamera.position.x = tpscamera.position.x + 1
> tpscamera.position.y = tpscamera.position.y - .4
> if tpscamera.position.x > 1:
> tpscamera.position.x = 1
> if tpscamera.position.y < 2.9:
> tpscamera.position.y = 2.9
> if Input.is_action_pressed("lean left") and Input.is_action_pressed("lean right"):
> tpscamera.position.x = 0
> 
> if equipped_weapon_1 or equipped_weapon_2 or equipped_weapon_3:
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("action 1") and anim_rig.current_animation != "shoot":
> play_shoot_effects.rpc()
> shooting = true
> if raycast.is_colliding():
> if raycast.get_collider() is CharacterBody3D:
> var hit_player = raycast.get_collider()
> print(raycast.get_collider().name)
> hit_player.attack.rpc_id(hit_player.get_multiplayer_authority())
> elif Input.is_action_just_released("action 1"):
> shooting = false
> stop_shoot_effects.rpc()
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("action 2") and not sprinting:
> aiming = true
> elif Input.is_action_just_released("action 2"):
> aiming = false
> fpscamera.position.x = 0
> fpscamera.position.z = -0.35
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("equipped 1") and weapon_1_id:
> equipped_weapon_2 = false
> equipped_weapon_3 = false
> weapon_model_2.visible = false
> weapon_model_3.visible = false
> if equipped_weapon_1:
> weapon.visible = false
> equipped_weapon_1 = false
> leftshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> rightshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> else:
> weapon.visible = true
> equipped_weapon_1 = true
> weapon_model_1.visible = true
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("equipped 2") and weapon_2_id:
> equipped_weapon_1 = false
> equipped_weapon_3 = false
> weapon_model_1.visible = false
> weapon_model_3.visible = false
> if equipped_weapon_2:
> weapon.visible = false
> equipped_weapon_2 = false
> leftshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> rightshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> else:
> weapon.visible = true
> equipped_weapon_2 = true
> weapon_model_2.visible = true
> 
> if Input.is_action_just_pressed("equipped 3") and weapon_3_id:
> equipped_weapon_1 = false
> equipped_weapon_2 = false
> weapon_model_1.visible = false
> weapon_model_2.visible = false
> if equipped_weapon_3:
> weapon.visible = false
> equipped_weapon_3 = false
> leftshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> rightshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> else:
> weapon.visible = true
> equipped_weapon_3 = true
> weapon_model_3.visible = true
> 
> func _physics_process(delta):
>   
>   if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
>   camera.current = true
>   var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "forward", "backward")
>   var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
>   
>   head.rotation = camera.rotation
>   tpshead.rotation.z = camera.rotation.y
>   tpshead.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x * -1
>   fpshealthbar.size.x = health
>   tpshealthbar.size.x = health
>   
>   get_slot_data()
>   
>   if inventory:
> interact_ray.enabled = false
> velocity.x = 0
> velocity.z = 0
>   if not inventory:
> interact_ray.enabled = true
>   
>   if not freelook:
> weapon.global_position = rightpalm.global_position
> weapon.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x
> 
>   if not pausing and not inventory:
> if direction:
> if crawling:
> velocity.x = direction.x * CRAWLSPEED
> velocity.z = direction.z * CRAWLSPEED
> elif crouching:
> velocity.x = direction.x * CROUCHSPEED
> velocity.z = direction.z * CROUCHSPEED
> elif sprinting:
> velocity.x = direction.x * SPRINTSPEED
> velocity.z = direction.z * SPRINTSPEED
> else:
> walking = true
> velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
> velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
> else:
> velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
> velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)
> 
>   if not is_on_floor():
> velocity.y -= gravity * delta
> 
>   if inspecting:
> weapon.rotation.y = righthand.rotation.y * -1
> weapon.rotation.x = righthand.rotation.x * -1
> anim_arms.play("arms inspect")
> 
>   if equipped_weapon_1 or equipped_weapon_2 or equipped_weapon_3:
> if not inspecting:
> weapon.rotation.y = 0
> anim_arms.play("arms weapon equipped")
> if not freelook and not sprinting and not crawling:
> leftshoulder.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x
> rightshoulder.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x * -1
>   if not equipped_weapon_1 and not equipped_weapon_2 and not equipped_weapon_3:
> anim_arms.play("arms idle")
> 
>   if crouching:
> anim_rig.play("rig crouch")
> fpscamera.position.y = fpscamera.position.y - .01
> if fpscamera.position.y < 1.8:
> fpscamera.position.y = 1.8
>   else:
> if camera == fpscamera:
> fpscamera.position.x = 0
> fpscamera.position.z = -0.35
> fpscamera.position.y = fpscamera.position.y + .1
> if fpscamera.position.y > 2.4:
> fpscamera.position.y = 2.4
> if crouching:
> fpscamera.position.y = 1.8
> 
> if camera == tpscamera:
> tpscamera.fov = 100
> 
>   if aiming:
> if camera == fpscamera:
> fpscamera.global_position = aimposition.global_position
> if camera == tpscamera:
> tpscamera.fov = 50
>   
>   if sprinting:
> aiming = false
> leftshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> rightshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> anim_arms.play("arms weapon sprinting")
> 
>   if crawling:
> aiming = false
> leftshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> rightshoulder.rotation.x = 0
> anim_arms.play("arms weapon crawling")
> 
>   if velocity.z == 0 and not crouching:
> anim_rig.play("rig idle")
>   if camera.position.x == -1:
> anim_tpsc.play("tpsc left")
>   if camera.position.x == 1:
> anim_tpsc.play("tpsc right")
>   if camera.position.x == 0:
> anim_tpsc.play("tpsc centered")
>   if camera == fpscamera:
> anim_tpsc.play("tpsc retracted")
>   if tpscamera.position.x == 0:
> tpscamera.position.y = 3.3
> 
>   move_and_slide()
> 
> 
> 
> @rpc("any_peer")
> func heal(heal_value: int):
> 
>   health += heal_value
>   if health > Globals.PlayerHealth:
> health = Globals.PlayerHealth
> 
> @rpc("any_peer")
> func attack():
>   var attack_value = 10
>   health -= attack_value
>   if health <= 0:
> health = Globals.PlayerHealth
> position = Vector3.ZERO
>   health_changed.emit(health)
> 
> @rpc("call_local")
> func play_shoot_effects():
> 
>   muzzle_flash.restart()
>   muzzle_flash.emitting = true
> 
> @rpc("call_local")
> func stop_shoot_effects():
> 
>   anim_weapon.stop()
>   muzzle_flash.emitting = false
> 
> 
> func toggle_inventory_interface(external_inventory_owner = null) -> void:
>   
>   if inventoryHUD.visible:
> inventory = false
> inventoryHUD.visible = false
> player_inventory.visible = false
> Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
> 
>   else:
> inventory = true
> inventoryHUD.visible = true
> player_inventory.visible = true
> Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE
> 
>   if external_inventory_owner and player_inventory.visible:
> player_inventory.set_external_inventory(external_inventory_owner)
>   else:
> player_inventory.clear_external_inventory()
> 
> func get_drop_position() -> Vector3:
>   
>   var PlayerFacing = -self.global_transform.basis.z
>   return fpscamera.global_position + PlayerFacing
> 
> func _on_inventory_drop_slot_data(grabbed_slot_data) -> void:
>   
>   print_debug("Sending object to server.")
>   drop_item.emit(grabbed_slot_data)
> 
> #func on_instantiate_pickup(grabbed_slot_data):
> var pick_up = PickUp.instantiate()
> pick_up.slot_data = grabbed_slot_data
> pick_up.position = Vector3(0,10,0)
> add_child(pick_up)
> 
> func get_slot_data() -> void:
>   
>   weapon_1_id = weapon_slot_1_data.slot_datas[0]
>   weapon_2_id = weapon_slot_2_data.slot_datas[0]
>   weapon_3_id = weapon_slot_3_data.slot_datas[0]
>   
>   if weapon_1_id == null:
> equipped_weapon_1 = false
> if weapon_model_1:
> weapon_model_1.visible = false
> 
>   elif weapon_1_id.item_data.name == "A55 Clipper":
> weapon_model_1 = $"Weapon/models/A55 Clipper"
>   elif weapon_1_id.item_data.name == "A22 Thumper":
> weapon_model_1 = $"Weapon/models/A22 Thumper"
>   elif weapon_1_id.item_data.name == "A33 Jackhammer":
> weapon_model_1 = $"Weapon/models/A33 Jackhammer"
> 
>   if weapon_2_id == null:
> equipped_weapon_2 = false
> if weapon_model_2:
> weapon_model_2.visible = false
> 
>   elif weapon_2_id.item_data.name == "A55 Clipper":
> weapon_model_2 = $"Weapon/models/A55 Clipper"
>   elif weapon_2_id.item_data.name == "A22 Thumper":
> weapon_model_2 = $"Weapon/models/A22 Thumper"
>   elif weapon_2_id.item_data.name == "A33 Jackhammer":
> weapon_model_2 = $"Weapon/models/A33 Jackhammer"
> 
>   if weapon_3_id == null:
> equipped_weapon_3 = false
> if weapon_model_3:
> weapon_model_3.visible = false
> 
>   elif weapon_3_id.item_data.name == "Rosen's Shadow":
> weapon_model_3 = $"Weapon/models/Exotic Rosen's Shadow"
>
```

Here is the full server code if you'd like to look through it.

```
> extends Node
> 
> var pos_dict = {}
> var players = {}
> 
> #signal instantiate_pickup(grabbed_slot_data)
> 
> enum lobby_status {Private, Friends, Public, Invisible}
> enum search_distance {Close, Default, Far, Worldwide}
> 
> @onready var main_menu = $CanvasLayer
> @onready var address_entry = $CanvasLayer/AddressEntry
> @onready var hud = $CanvasLayer/HUD
> @onready var health_bar = $CanvasLayer/HUD/HealthBar
> 
> @onready var connection_timer = $ConnectionTimer
> 
> @onready var steam_name = $CanvasLayer/SteamName
> @onready var lobby_name = steam_name
> @onready var lobby_output = $CanvasLayer/Chat/RichTextLabel
> @onready var player_count = $CanvasLayer/Players/Playercount
> @onready var player_list = $CanvasLayer/Players/RichTextLabel
> @onready var chat_input = $CanvasLayer/Chat/SendMessage/TextEdit
> 
> @onready var keybinds_panel = $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel/KeybindsButton/KeybindsPanel
> @onready var video_panel = $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel/VideoButton/VideoPanel
> @onready var audio_panel = $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel/AudioButton/AudioPanel
> @onready var chat_panel = $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel/ChatButton/ChatPanel
> @onready var accessibility_panel = $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel/AccessibilityButton/AccessibilityPanel
> 
> @onready var PickUp = preload("res://item/pickup/pickup.tscn")
> 
> const Player = preload("res://player/player.tscn")
> const PORT = 9999
> 
> var enet_peer = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> func _process(_delta):
> 
>   $CanvasLayer/DisconnectTimer/Timer.text = str(ceil($ConnectionTimer.time_left))
>   if address_entry.text == "":
>       $CanvasLayer/JoinButton.disabled = true
>   else:
>       $CanvasLayer/JoinButton.disabled = false
> 
> 
> 
> func _unhandled_input(_event):
> 
>   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("quit"):
> if main_menu.visible:
> main_menu.visible = false
> Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
> else:
> main_menu.visible = true
> Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE
> 
> 
> 
> func _on_connection_timer_timeout():
> 
>   get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://world.tscn")
>   $CanvasLayer/DisconnectTimer.visible = false
>   Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE
>   print_debug("Connection to the server timed out.")
> 
> func add_player(peer_id):
>   
>   var player = Player.instantiate()
>   player.name = str(peer_id)
>   add_child(player)
>   players[peer_id] = player
>   player.drop_item.connect(_on_inventory_drop_slot_data)
>   if player.drop_item.is_connected(_on_inventory_drop_slot_data):
> print_debug("This is connecting to",player)
>   if player.is_multiplayer_authority():
> player.health_changed.connect(update_health_bar)
> 
> func remove_player(peer_id):
>   
>   var player = get_node_or_null(str(peer_id))
>   if player:
> player.queue_free()
> 
> func update_health_bar(health_value):
> 
>   health_bar.value = health_value
> 
> func _on_multiplayer_spawner_spawned(node):
> 
>   if node.is_multiplayer_authority():
> node.health_changed.connect(update_health_bar)
> 
>   
> func upnp_setup():
> 
>   var upnp = UPNP.new()
>   var discover_result = upnp.discover()
>   assert(discover_result == UPNP.UPNP_RESULT_SUCCESS, \
>       "UPNP Discover Failed! Error %s" % discover_result)
>   assert(upnp.get_gateway() and upnp.get_gateway().is_valid_gateway(), \
>       "UPNP Invalid Gateway!")
> 
>   var map_result = upnp.add_port_mapping(PORT)
>   assert(map_result == UPNP.UPNP_RESULT_SUCCESS, \
>       "UPNP Port Mapping Failed! Error %s" % map_result)
>   print("Success! Join Address: %s" % upnp.query_external_address())
> 
> func _on_inventory_drop_slot_data(grabbed_slot_data) -> void:
>   print_debug("Server is receiving object.")
>   if grabbed_slot_data:
> print_debug(grabbed_slot_data)
>   else:
> print_debug("no slot data")
>   var pick_up = PickUp.instantiate()
>   pick_up.slot_data = grabbed_slot_data
>   pick_up.position = Vector3(0,10,0)
>   add_child(pick_up)
> 
> func _on_host_button_pressed():
> 
>   main_menu.hide()
>   hud.show()
>   $CanvasLayer/HostButton.disabled = true
>   $CanvasLayer/JoinButton.disabled = true
>   $CanvasLayer/JoinLocal.disabled = true
>   $CanvasLayer/AddressEntry.editable = false
>   $CanvasLayer/LeaveButton.disabled = false
>   $CanvasLayer/Background.visible = false
>   enet_peer.create_server(PORT)
>   multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = enet_peer
>   multiplayer.peer_connected.connect(add_player)
>   multiplayer.peer_disconnected.connect(remove_player)
>   add_player(multiplayer.get_unique_id())
>   upnp_setup()
> 
> func _on_join_button_pressed():
>   
>   enet_peer.create_client(address_entry.text, PORT)
>   multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = enet_peer
>   connection_timer.start()
>   $CanvasLayer/LeaveButton.disabled = false
>   $CanvasLayer/DisconnectTimer.visible = true
>   enet_peer.get_connection_status()
>   if enet_peer.get_connection_status() == 1:
> main_menu.hide()
>       $CanvasLayer/HostButton.disabled = true
>       $CanvasLayer/JoinButton.disabled = true
>       $CanvasLayer/JoinLocal.disabled = true
>       $CanvasLayer/AddressEntry.editable = false
>       $CanvasLayer/Background.visible = false
> connection_timer.stop()
>       $CanvasLayer/DisconnectTimer.visible = false
> print_debug("Connected to the server!")
> 
> func _on_join_local_pressed():
>   
>   enet_peer.create_client("localhost", PORT)
>   multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = enet_peer
>   connection_timer.start()
>   $CanvasLayer/LeaveButton.disabled = false
>   $CanvasLayer/DisconnectTimer.visible = true
>   enet_peer.get_connection_status()
>   if enet_peer.get_connection_status() == 1:
> main_menu.hide()
>       $CanvasLayer/HostButton.disabled = true
>       $CanvasLayer/JoinButton.disabled = true
>       $CanvasLayer/JoinLocal.disabled = true
>       $CanvasLayer/AddressEntry.editable = false
>       $CanvasLayer/Background.visible = false
> connection_timer.stop()
>       $CanvasLayer/DisconnectTimer.visible = false
> print_debug("Connected to the server!")
> 
> func _on_leave_button_pressed():
> 
>   enet_peer.close()
>   get_tree().reload_current_scene()
>   $CanvasLayer/JoinButton.disabled = true
>   $CanvasLayer/JoinLocal.disabled = true
>   $CanvasLayer/AddressEntry.editable = true
>   $CanvasLayer/HostButton.disabled = false
>   $CanvasLayer/LeaveButton.disabled = false
>   $CanvasLayer/Background.visible = true
>   print_debug("Returning to the Menu.")
> 
> func _on_exit_button_pressed():
> 
>   get_tree().quit()
> 
> func _on_settings_button_pressed():
>   if $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel.visible == true:
>       $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel.visible = false
>   else:
>       $CanvasLayer/SettingsPanel.visible = true
> 
> func _on_keybinds_button_pressed():
>   if keybinds_panel.visible == true:
> keybinds_panel.visible = false
>   else:
> keybinds_panel.visible = true
> video_panel.visible = false
> audio_panel.visible = false
> chat_panel.visible = false
> accessibility_panel.visible = false
> 
> func _on_video_button_pressed():
>   if video_panel.visible == true:
> video_panel.visible = false
>   else:
> video_panel.visible = true
> keybinds_panel.visible = false
> audio_panel.visible = false
> chat_panel.visible = false
> accessibility_panel.visible = false
> 
> func _on_audio_button_pressed():
>   if audio_panel.visible == true:
> audio_panel.visible = false
>   else:
> audio_panel.visible = true
> video_panel.visible = false
> keybinds_panel.visible = false
> chat_panel.visible = false
> accessibility_panel.visible = false
> 
> func _on_chat_button_pressed():
>   if chat_panel.visible == true:
> chat_panel.visible = false
>   else:
> chat_panel.visible = true
> video_panel.visible = false
> audio_panel.visible = false
> keybinds_panel.visible = false
> accessibility_panel.visible = false
> 
> func _on_accessibility_button_pressed():
>   if accessibility_panel.visible == true:
> accessibility_panel.visible = false
>   else:
> accessibility_panel.visible = true
> video_panel.visible = false
> audio_panel.visible = false
> chat_panel.visible = false
> keybinds_panel.visible = false
>
```

I tried emitting a signal from a client connected to a server, and the signal confirmed to be connecting when testing "is_connected", but the client was not taking the data from the emission and executing a function.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem, I needed to connect the signal TWICE. This is where I had to connect a second time:

```
func _on_multiplayer_spawner_spawned(node):
    if node.is_multiplayer_authority():
        node.health_changed.connect(update_health_bar)
        node.drop_item.connect(_on_inventory_drop_slot_data)
```